# Getting classnames, splitting it and writing array to div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a bar where users can toggle "buyers".
When a user selects one of the buyers jquery does an addClass("selectBuyerOn")

When user selects submit a new div appears and I would like the list of Buyer names to appear there.

```
        <div class="buyerNames">
           <div class="buyer b1">BUYERNAME ONE</div>
           <div class="buyer b2">BUYERNAME TWO</div>
           <div class="buyer b3">BUYERNAME THREE</div>

           ...
        </div>
```

So I searched by className "selectBuyerOn"

and put it into an array
and tested via console.log

so far so good.

```
var elemBuyerOn=document.getElementsByClassName("selectBuyerOn");
var arr=jQuery.makeArray(elemBuyerOn);
console.log(arr);
```

But now I can't seem to append the array to a div.

```
$(".listOfItems").append(arr);
```

I must be missing something simple here.

Signed by: "Damn It Jim, I'm a UX Designer Not Front-End Engineer"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add the values in the array one by one. This should work:

```
$.each(arr, function(index, value) {
$('.listofitems').append(arr[index]);
});
```

So basically, for each item in the array, append it to listofitems.

Comment: Not working. I will try again and see if I can clarify my question (and perhaps my coding).

Comment: Working in this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ray9209/jyjaubwv/3/. Can you make edits there, click update, and send me the new link?

Comment: Thanks. The problem is not in the appending but somewhere else. I troubleshooted everything (and thanks by the way for your jsfiddle) and the problem is elsewhere.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.map` on that class to get a list of buyers and then join them:

```
var buyers = $(".selectBuyerOn").map(function() {
    return $(this).text();
}).get().join(",");

//buyers is now a list of the selected buyers

$(".listOfItems").append(buyers);
```

Comment: Not working. I will try again and see if I can clarify my question (and perhaps my coding).

Comment: Was pulled off onto a new project. Couldn't think about this problem until today. I solved this problem in a roundabout way. The issue was less the array than the fact that the array is wiped clean and re-populated each time when someone clicks. Solved it by saving it server-side. (Had to keep going.)  When I have time I will come back to this problem because I want to find out why it didn't work.